# Ternary operator in the render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show a message if the user is not logged in.
Please Login here to continue.

In my render method, I need to check to see if the user is already logged in to not show any message.
I also have a login method that directs user to the login page. (

```
{
  this.props.isAuthed 
    ? <div> </div>
    : <div> Please login<Button color="inherit" onClick={this.login}>here</Button></div>
}
```

I have two problems. One is the above if statement doesn't work because it's not an if else statement. (The only solution I found is adding an empty `<div>`)

The other issue is I need to show a button to look like a hyperlinked text because I can't call the `this.login` function in a `href`. Now there's a big space (because of the button) between "login" and "here". I also need to make "here" red to inform the user that it's clickable.

Comment: The `?` part can be just `""` no?

Comment: yes but it's not different from the empty div that I mentioned.

Comment: Hanna, please ask a second question for the second problem you have. These are two totally unrelated issues.

Comment: `I can't call the this.login function in a href` - why is that?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth ok, can you suggest me a good title for that?

Comment: the `?` can simply just be `null` if you wanted.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar because it's not a string. I'm using auth0 and I can't add a link instead of the function.

Comment: why not? `<a onClick={}>`??

Comment: so you can not add onlick to an anchor?

Comment: I tried `<div> Please login <a onClick={this.login}>here</a></div>` but it didn't work. Only the button can add a link and I don't know the reason.

Comment: not sure what the issue is, how does the anchor render? without the underline? That is probaly because there is on href attribute.

Comment: @epascarello It looks like a simple text. I asked the question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398845/calling-auth0-login-in-href

Comment: so than add an href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple boolean expression:

```
 {!this.props.isAuthed &&
  <div> Please login<Button color="inherit" onClick={this.login}>here</Button></div>
 }
```

Comment: thanks! do you have any solution for the second problem?