# Calling auth0 login in href

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, auth0

I'm trying to show a message if the user is not logged in. Please Login here (red color) to continue.

In the render method, I need to check and see if the user is already logged in to not show any message.
I also have a login method that directs user to the login page.

I need to show a button to look like a hyperlinked text because I can't call the `this.login` function in a `href`. Now there's a big space (because of the button) between "login" and "here". I also need to make "here" red to inform the user that it's clickable.

I tried `<div> Please login <a onClick={this.login}>here</a></div>` but it "here" looks like a simple text. No link appears. Only the button can add a link and I don't know the reason.

```
{!this.props.isAuthed && <div> Please login<Button color="inherit" onClick={this.login}>here</Button></div>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div> Please login <a onClick={this.login} href="#">here</a></div>
```

The reason is: An `a` tag without the `href` attribute is not rendered like a link by browsers. To mitigate that, we add it with some arbitrary value.

On your `onClick` handler - `login` in your case - you need to ensure that you prevent the default action - navigating to the relative url `#` - from happening:

```
login = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your login logic
}
```

Comment: great! It works now without the changing the handler. Can you please explain more about that?

Comment: I think I already explained it in detail. Please re-read my answer. If something is still unclear, please specify exactly what